# Creating a new object when writing to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an app that has some form fields. When the form is submitted it writes the data to my Core Data Object. However, when the form is submitted again it overwrites the existing data instead of appending to it, which is what I want to happen instead.

```swift
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let userEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: managedContext)

    let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: userEntity! , insertInto: managedContext)
    newUser.setValue(titleField, forKey: "title")
    newUser.setValue(firstNameField, forKey: "firstName")
    newUser.setValue(lastNameField, forKey: "lastName")
    newUser.setValue(emailField, forKey: "email")
    newUser.setValue(affiliatedOrgField, forKey: "affiliatedOrg")
    newUser.setValue(ukRegionField, forKey: "ukRegion")
    newUser.setValue(privacyChecked, forKey: "privacyPolicy")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

I have tried using

```
let userEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "User", into: managedContext)
let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: userEntity, insertInto: managedContext)
```

but I get the following error on my 'newUser' constant

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSManagedObject' to expected argument type 'NSEntityDescription'

Can anybody help please?

Comment: For this purpose you have to use sqlite db.

Comment: @MaulikPatel That comment makes no sense. To the question, the code creates a new object every time it executes and does not look up existing objects at all, so it's hard to tell how your problem would happen. Do you maybe have a uniqueness constraint on one of the fields? Maybe the email address field?

Comment: You don't need the last line of code. You need just `let userEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "User", into: managedContext) as! User`

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using `NSPersistentContainer` you are using at least macOS 10.12 or iOS 10.10. Apple has added some very nice simplifications to Core Data so that it is unnecessary, for example, to use string-based keys which have the disadvantage to being resistant to compiler checking.

The “new Core Data pattern” looks like this:

```
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let newUser = User(context: managedContext)
newUser.title = ...
newUser.firstName = ...
```

It could be as simple as that. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep a reference to your newly created user and then update that user. So do as Tom E suggested

```
let newUser = User(context: managedContext)
newUser.title = ...
newUser. firstName = ...
```

Then let newUser be a property in your class of type User or part of an array, [User], depending on your use case

```
var newUser: User?
```

When the form gets updated then instead of creating a new user, update the changed properties like

```
newUser.email = emailField
```

and call save to persist the update

```
try managedContext.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the object to `User`:

```
let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "User", into: managedContext) as! User
...<fill the fields>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way:

```
let newUser = User(entity: User.entity(), insertInto: managedContext)
```